# Oracle SQL if statement?

Tags: sql, oracle

how would it be possible to check if a certain value in salesman_id is null, and if it is, assign it to something else (in this case, 0)?

here's what i've wrote up so far:

```
SELECT O.SALESMAN_ID, SUM(OI.UNIT_PRICE * QUANTITY)
FROM ORDERS O, ORDER_ITEMS OI
GROUP BY O.SALESMAN_ID
ORDER BY O.SALESMAN_ID;
```

Comment: Standard SQL: 1. `case when salesman_id is null then 0 else salesman_id end` 2. `coalesce(salesman_id, 0)` And Oracle specific: 3. `nvl(salesman_id, 0)` 4. `decode(salesman_id, null, 0, salesman_id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
SELECT COALESCE(O.SALESMAN_ID, 0) as SALESMAN_ID, SUM(OI.UNIT_PRICE * QUANTITY)
FROM ORDERS O JOIN
     ORDER_ITEMS OI
     ON o.ORDER_ID = OI.ORDER_ID. -- guessing at the relationship
GROUP BY COALESCE(O.SALESMAN_ID, 0)
ORDER BY COALESCE(O.SALESMAN_ID, 0);
```

Your query as written would produce non-sensical results.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT nvl(O.SALESMAN_ID,0), SUM(OI.UNIT_PRICE * QUANTITY)
FROM ORDERS O, ORDER_ITEMS OI
GROUP BY nvl(O.SALESMAN_ID,0)
ORDER BY 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness sake, a further option would be...

```
SELECT salesman_id, SUM(total)
FROM (
    SELECT CASE WHEN o.salesman_id IS NULL 
           THEN 0 
           ELSE o.salesman_id as SALESMAN_ID, 
     OI.UNIT_PRICE * QUANTITY AS total 
    FROM ORDERS O JOIN
     ORDER_ITEMS OI
     ON o.ORDER_ID = OI.ORDER_ID
  ) AS ilv
GROUP BY salesman_id;
```

But null is a value too....

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ilv.salesman_id IS NULL 
           THEN 0 
           ELSE ilv.salesman_id as SALESMAN_ID,
    total
FROM (
    SELECT salesman_id 
     SUM(OI.UNIT_PRICE * QUANTITY) AS total 
    FROM ORDERS O JOIN
     ORDER_ITEMS OI
     ON o.ORDER_ID = OI.ORDER_ID
    GROUP BY sles,an_id
  ) AS ilv;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the query is incorrect, you need to join orders and ORDER_ITEMS using order_id

scott

Comment: Yes the OP's query is missing a join - but this should be posted as a coment, not an answer. And we don't know what attributes implement the join.

Comment: sorry, I am less than 50 reputation, so I can not post as comment.

Comment: I will remember next time, just try to help